# Check the solr query generated by haystack

Tags: django, python-2.7, solr, lucene, django-haystack

Is there any way to get the solr query generated by haystack?

e.g I want to check what query is generated when I do SearchQuerySet.facet('some_field_name')?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to this problem.

In the file pysolr.py, uncomment the following lines:

```
#print 'path: ',path
#print 'body:',body
```

The generated solr query will be displayed in the console.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the actual query seen by Solr by configuring [SolrLogging](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrLogging) to show the information you're looking for. `INFO` should be enough for the actual query received to be shown.